# XSLT change the value of a tag if parameter matches

Tags: java, xslt

I've a task to rewrite the form "action" parameter to change from relative to absolute URL. Also, in the same form I've to check if the "method" is "GET" I've to change it to post and have to pass extra hidden parameter with original method value. For eg:

```
<form name="my_form" action="submitForm.action" method="get">
    some fields
</form>
```

This should change to:

```
<form name="my_form" action="http://localhost:8080/submitForm.action" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="method" value="get"/>
    some fields
</form>
```

Is it possible to change this via XSLT? What could be my XSLT in that case? I've tried various options but I'm able to change only one parameter of FORM and do not know how will I add an extra field to form.

I'm using Java to rewrite and transform.

Thanks in advance.

-Rikin

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to transform HTML into HTML with xsl.

You would probably have to write an xsl a little like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/form">
    <xsl:variable name="abs-action" select="concat('http://blablabla:8080/', @action)"/>
    <form method="POST">
        <xsl:attribute name="name" select="@name"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="action" select="$abs-action"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="hidden-input"></input>
    </form>
</xsl:template>
```

You can always surround parts of this code by xsl:if to test for the attributes of the form (For example the "method" attribute).

Hope this helps a bit.

Tristan

Comment: Thanks Tristan for your response. Probably my mistake, I might not be clear enough. My requirement is bit different. To re-write action parameter I've to use Java code. Also, form has many fields as shown in question. With this it'll overwrite other parameters, I feel!